# MS Word Pro 2016 wildcard detailed description

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, wildcards

Is there a MS Word Pro 2016 wildcard detailed description available? The only descriptions from Microsoft that I can find describe only the basic syntax with a few simple examples.
The basic syntax is incomplete and does not describe all variants,
for example, [] - One of the specified characters
By trial-and-error, I found that ranges can also be specified (as well as combinations. Similarly, I have encountered parsing problems:

- `[a-z]{1,}`   OK
- `[a-z]{1,}our` NOK
- `[a-z]@our`   OK
- `[a-z]{1,2}our`  OK
- `[a-z]{1}our`   OK

Is some detailed description available or must remain with trial-and-error?

Answer (score 0):

Although not official Microsoft sites, there are two I can recommend for information on wildcard searching.

The first is Graham Mayor's site. Graham contributed to many of the articles that Microsoft used to have on their support site concerning wildcards.
http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm

The other is the Word MVP site:
https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm

Comment: Thanks Rich, far better than the "official" MS documentation.